# Adding data to a plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I drew a line plot spanning over a certain period, say 2010-2020, and I'm trying to add the new data of 2021 to the plot without having to merge the old and new data and just add to the already existing plot. Is it possible to do this ? And does it have to be a line plot too or can I make it a scatter plot for 2021 instead ?

Here's the code I used to draw the line plot of the first period :

```
mask = (data1['Date'] >= '2010-01-01') & (data1['Date'] < '2021-01-01')
Dates = list(map(pd.to_datetime, data1[mask]['Date'].unique()))

plt.plot(Dates, Data_Value_max,'-', color='green')
plt.plot(Dates, Data_Value_min,'-', color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you show some code with how you have your plots?

Comment: There, I just added it

Comment: Just try adding another `plt.plot()` with the new data you have, before the `plt.show()` line. This should add that data as well to the plot. If you want a scatter instead of a line, add `plt.scatter()`. If that helps, I will post it as an answer

Comment: When I first made the plot, the x axis was 2010-2020, now I'm trying to plot some new data for 2021, so in a way the question is how can I expand the x axis

Comment: Then what you are looking for would be to set the xlimits. You can do that using `plt.xlim(left_limit, right_limit)`. Check the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html